# How do you stop the dag started with TriggerDagRunOperator?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

In my parent dag, I have a child dag started with the `TriggerDagRunOperator`. That child dag goes ahead and does its own thing.

```python
my_trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
  task_id = "my_trigger",
  trigger_dag_id = "child_dag",
  wait_for_completion = True,
  execution_date="{{ logical_date }}",
)
```

However, somewhere down the line in my parent dag, something fails and I just want to stop everything. There's no point in the child dag still running if something failed in the parent dag.

I can set the state of the `my_trigger` task to `State.FAILED` and that will fail the task, but it won't stop the child dag from continuing to run until it completes.

So my question is how do you do stop the dag started by the `TriggerDagRunOperator`? I looked around members of `my_trigger` but I couldn't really find anything that would let me stop the dag. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out you cannot use the `TriggerDagRunOperator` to stop the dag it started.

This is not even how it works internally in Airflow. In order to stop a dag, you  must stop all its tasks. Setting a dag to a failed state *will not work*!

Therefore, the solution is to stop all of a dag's tasks. You can use `DagRun.find` to find the dag you are concerned with:

```python
dag_run = DagRun.find(
  dag_id = my_trigger.trigger_dag_id,
  execution_date = kwargs["logical_date"],
)[0]
```

Then, stop all its tasks in order to stop the dag:

```python
for task_instance in dag_run.get_task_instances():
  if task_instance.current_state() in (
    State.RUNNING, # there may be more states to check ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    State.SCHEDULED,
    State.UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE,
  ):
    task_instance.set_state(State.FAILED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch the UI and find the DAG in the DAG List. Select each Task instance that is running or queued or scheduled, etc. and change the status to "failed". Then select the DAG instance and set the status to "failed".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking for a more programmatic way to do it with only code. This way, the dag will stop itself automatically without me having to navigate some ui.